# rearranging listview items

Tags: c++, winapi, listview

Say I have a listview control with several items in it. How would I allow the user to drag and drop items to rearrange them in the control.

The listview control is in report view, with the full-row select extended style.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ListView's `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` handler, store the currently selected item index somewhere.

In your ListView's `WM_LBUTTONUP` handler, use `ListView_HitTest()` to determine which item is under the cursor.  If different than the stored index, then use `ListView_DeleteItem()` and `ListView_InsertItem()` to "move" the "dragged" item to the new index.

(Optionally) To help the user see where the item is being "dragged" to, in your ListView's `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler, use `ListView_HitTest()` to determine which item is under the cursor, then use `ListView_SetItemState()` to disable/enable the `LVIS_DROPHILITED` state for the previously "highlighted" item (if any) and to "highlight" the current item.